# In the Table Design execute a SELECT statement to set the default value of a table column

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Here is the table:

[image]

In the default property of RegionID I want to execute this SELECT statement to establish the value of the cell when a new row is added:

```
select regionID from tRegion where IsNone = 1
```

When I try to save the table design I get
"Error validating the default for column 'RegionID'.

Here is the tRegion table:
[image]

Comment: You can't define a `DEFAULT` value with a `SELECT` statement; it must be a scalar expression.

Comment: What do you want to happen if there are multiple regions with IsNone=1?

Comment: @StuartAinsworth Why do you think that could happen?

Comment: @nicomp unless you’ve got a constraint to restrict it to one row, then multiple rows are possible (which will break the function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the limitations of `Computed Column` is it can't directly access any column outside its table. So you can alternatively create a `User Defined Function`as:

```
  -- Create UDF to use in computed column
CREATE FUNCTION UDF_GetDefaultRegionId ()
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @DefRegionId int
  SELECT @DefRegionId = regionID 
  from tRegion 
  where IsNone = 1

  RETURN @DefRegionId
END;
```

and then use in the Test table as:

```
CREATE TABLE Test
( 
  StoreId int,
  --set default value here:
  RegionId  as ([dbo].UDF_GetDefaultRegionId())
 )
```

[Sample code here..](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=8a18639d84140d9119e32d4654ec66c0).Hope this helps!!!

Comment: It's worth noting that functions like this can have significant performance impacts. if you're inserting a lot of rows, the speed at which the RDBMS does so will be far slower, as the UDF will be run once per row in the `INSERT` (not once for the entire dataset).

Comment: Yes, I agree this approach will have performance impact if a large dataset is being inserted but for given situation I think this is the only way around.